# upgrade APNS binary protocol to the enhanced HTTP/2-based API

Tags: binary, apple-push-notifications, http2

I recently received the mail below from Apple

> We noticed that your apps may be communicating with the Apple Push Notification service through the binary protocol. Since this is a legacy protocol, we recommend updating to the enhanced HTTP/2-based API as soon as possible. You’ll be able to take advantage of great new features, such as authentication with a JSON Web Token, improved error messaging, and per-notification feedback.

I have no idea what to do :
1 - do I have to modify something in my app and how ?
2 - do I have to modify something on my server (certainely) but how ?

Any help welcome.
Have a nice day.

Comment: How do you send your push notifications? Do you use a library? If so, does the documentation of the lib give any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I recommend you to read official documentation about benefits of new **http/2** based apns service. Then if you want to use newly introduced features you can change your server-side implementation to be able to send notifications over new API. But, according to feature that you want to use, of course there might be some changes on your client code.

Otherwise there is no need to change anything on both side for now until Apple decide to close the legacy api. As you can see they call it **legacy**, It's better to prepare yourself for the stressful time.

If we come to how you can use new API on server-side, I recommend you to read these two page carefully:

[Setting Up a Remote Notification Server](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server?language=objc)

[Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc)

Or, depends on your programming language, but maybe you can find some libraries which make it easy to use by using google.

Comment: Seems apple is going to stop support for the legacy APNS API from April,2021.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=c88acm2b